# SQL update : deduplication of email address by adding + ID before @

Tags: mysql, sql, email, duplicates

I'm trying to update a clients table in mySQL containing duplicate email addresses and a unique custom_ID. I would like to change duplicate email addresses by adding a '+' and customer_ID before the @ sign, but only for the email addresses that are not unique.

```
UPDATE clients SET email = REPLACE(email,'@', CONCAT('+',custom_ID,'@'))

INPUT
+-----------+-------------------------+
| custom_ID | email                   |
+-----------+-------------------------+
|  1001     | john.smith@live.com     |
|  1002     |    evyandy@email.net    |
|  1007     |    evyandy@email.net    |
|  1012     |        ann@live.com     |
|  1020     |       rick@yahoo.com    |
|  1021     |        ann@live.com     |
|  1023     |    evyandy@email.net    |
|  1024     |       emma@gmail.com    |
+-----------+-------------------------+

 OUTPUT
+-----------+----------------------------+
| custom_ID | email                      |
+-----------+----------------------------+
|  1001     |   john.smith@live.com      |
|  1002     |      evyandy@email.net     |
|  1007     | evyandy+1007@email.net     |
|  1012     |          ann@live.com      |
|  1020     |         rick@yahoo.com     |
|  1021     |     ann+1021@live.com      |
|  1023     | evyandy+1023@email.net     |
|  1024     |         emma@gmail.com     |
+-----------+----------------------------+
```

Comment: You should be aware that not all email providers use `+` in the same way. There is no guarantee that `user+1@host.com` and `user+2@host.com`  are delivered to the same person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `update` with window functions and a `join`:

```
update clients c join
       (select c.*, row_number() over (partition by email order by custom_id) as seqnum
        from clients cc
       ) cc
       on c.custom_id = cc.custom_id
    set email = concat(substring_index(email, '@', 1), '+', custom_id, '@', substring_index(email, '@', -1))
    where cc.seqnum > 1;
```